# Cannot find -lmysqlcppconn

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse

Many topics regarding the connector, but I haven't found my answer.

I'm trying to implement the MySQL C++ connector. I have added the following search path to my (Cross G++) linker: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.7\lib"`following by adding the `mysqlcppconn` and `mysqlcppconn-static` to the library's.

Within the  ++ compiler section I have added two paths: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.7\include"` and the added `include\cppconn` path. Hereby the three `header` files are included.

When building the project the build console says: `cannot find -lmysqlcppconn` and `-lmysqlcppconn-static`

Comment: And the library files are in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.7\lib` directory? How are you linking your program? Are you using an IDE? Which compiler and linker are you using?

Comment: yes, the library files are located in that directory. I'm using eclipse CDT (C++ project), cross G++ compiler and G++ linker.

Comment: And just to be sure, the library files are named e.g. `libmysqlcppconn.a`?

Comment: No, those are `.lib` files in combination with an `.dll` The `.dll` is placed in the eclipse project directory.

Comment: The `.lib` files are for use with the Visual Studio compiler and linker, not the GNU linker. You need to find a package for your environment (probably MinGW) of build yourself from source using the cross GNU toolchain.